# I just cloned a react app to my local computer from github, but when I go to run an npm start on it, I get this error:

Tags: reactjs, github, npm

I just cloned a react app to my local computer from GitHub, and I set npm install but when I go to run an npm start on it, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\NOUREDDINE\Desktop\Redux>npm start
npm ERR! path C:\Users\NOUREDDINE\Desktop\Redux\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\NOUREDDINE\Desktop\Redux\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NOUREDDINE\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-06T21_34_57_558Z-debug.logand
```

Comment: Did you do `npm install` first? Also check you have the right version of node and npm.

Comment: I have "6.7.0" version for npm and " v10.15.0 " for node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to go to that folder where package.json resides and open cmd by pressing SHIFT+ right click on that folder(please check path, it should be correct), then do `npm install`, after that do `npm start`.

If it's worked fine then good and if you already installed the dependency then do the following things:

1. Delete Node_modules and package-lock.json file
2. clear cache  (`npm cache clean --force`) or by going to these
   folders
   c:/users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache and c:/users/username/AppData/Roaming/npm
3. then do `npm install` again

that might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone from the repo it comes with pakage.json which lists all of the dependencies and their respective versions, that are utilized by the app. It doesn't however include these dependencies. In order to run the app you need to navigate to the directory that houses the package.json file in the console and run "npm install". this will create the node_modules directory and download all of the necessary packages. then you can run "npm start".